# Travis android build error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/travis/build/ir2pid/AndroidPOC2/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 4.0.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/travis/build/ir2pid/AndroidPOC2/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.1-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 40s

travis_time:end:06d6b207:start=1527276803217824665,finish=1527276844181358996,duration=40963534331
[0K
[31;1mThe command "gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.1" failed and exited with 1 during .[0m

Your build has been stopped.
```

1. I uploaded gradlew, gradle-wrapper.properties, gradle-wrapper.jar
2. tried making gradlew and gradle-wrapper.jar writable in .travis.yml
3. and even installed gradle 4.4 in .travis.yml script

> gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Fri May 25 21:05:26 CEST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

> .travis.yml

```
install: gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.4
language: android
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools

    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-26.0.2

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-26

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - addon-google_apis-google-26

before_script:
- chmod a+x gradlew
- chmod a+x gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

script: gradlew build
```

Comment: Still not solved?

Answer (score 0):

Compare this code to your's, pay attention to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
}
```

Top-level gradle build file (**build.gradle**):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        //To get a Git project into your build
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        //To get a Git project into your build
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**:

```
#Mon Jan 1 13:51:26 PDT 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-bin.zip
```

Comment: I am aiming at the latest versions both in gradle file 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' and in gradle-wrapper.properties "//services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't add `./` before gradlew!

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools

    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-26.0.2

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-26

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - addon-google_apis-google-26

before_script:
- chmod a+x gradlew

script: ./gradlew build
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working config of the same project.

> travis.yml

```
language: android

env:
  matrix:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-19 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools

    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-26.0.2

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-19
    - android-26

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - addon-google_apis-google-26
    - extra-android-support
    - sys-img-${ANDROID_ABI}-${ANDROID_TARGET}

script:
  - ./gradlew build 
  #- ./gradlew lint test connectedAndroidTest 
  #- ./gradlew build jacocoTestReport --stacktrace
```

> gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

> project level .gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

> app level .gradle
>       android {

```
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx.xx.xx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```